# POST 500 (Internal Error) php

Tags: php, ajax, post, http-post, http-status-code-500

I have this error.I've looked for solution in internet,but not found.
[image]

```js
function sendPhoto()
{
    var time = vaxt(new Date());

    $(".mes-all").append("<div class=\"mes-my\"><span class=\"mes-targering\"><span class=\"foto\"><i class=\"fa fa-circle-o-notch fa-spin\" style=\"font-size:30px;color:black\"></i></span></span><span style=\"display:inline\" class=\"mes-my-tr\">"+time+" <i class=\"fa fa-spinner fa-spin\" style=\"margin-left: 4px;\"></i></span></div>");

    scroll();

    var fd = new FormData();    

    fd.append( "file", $(".mes-sending-photo")[0].files[0]);
    fd.append( "to",$(".id").val());

    $.ajax({
        url: "ajax/sendPhoto.php",
        data: fd,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        type: "POST",
        success: function(){
            getMessage();
        }
    });
}
```

I think problem is at server side not at codes,but also I can't find.
error response:
Remote Address:46.17.40.62:80
Request URL:http://masters.az/ajax/sendPhoto.php
Request Method:POST
Status Code:500 Internal Server Error
Request Headersview parsed
POST /ajax/sendPhoto.php HTTP/1.1
Host: masters.az
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 159591
Accept: */*
Origin: http://masters.az
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.120 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----
WebKitFormBoundaryB8Wq6VD8CcBe7y9A
Referer: http://masters.az/message-4
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Cookie: login=fuad; parol=12345; id=2; cuid=Mw%3D%3D; 
cups=ac4b3abea4ff5ffb14f92d05d18f3c68; login=fuad; parol=12345; id=2; 
session=P7ytO93YItgRjUerd5PgJmrO5gN7KIrjPpdlweIDVyeFRG44LTkeDa0IGONagEI4
Request Payload
------WebKitFormBoundaryB8Wq6VD8CcBe7y9A
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="logo.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg

------WebKitFormBoundaryB8Wq6VD8CcBe7y9A
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="to"

4
------WebKitFormBoundaryB8Wq6VD8CcBe7y9A--
Response Headersview source
Connection:close
Content-Length:594
Content-Type:text/html
Date:Thu, 04 Feb 2016 16:40:13 GMT
Server:nginx/1.6.2

The php code is(that content sending by via ajax):

```
<?php
if($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] == 'XMLHttpRequest') {
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
require("../inc/core.php");
$file=$_FILES['file'];
$tip=$file['type'];
$size=$file['size'];
$t=time();
$yer="../files/mes_images/".$t."_big.png";
$access_size=5*(1000000);
$access_type=array("image/gif","image/jpg","image/jpeg","image/pjpeg","image/x-png","image/png");
if(in_array($tip,$access_type) && $size<=$access_size && !empty($file['name'])){
$q=move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'],$yer);
echo $q?"ok":"no";
resize($yer,null,100,100,false,"../files/mes_images/".$t.".png",false,false,100);

$mes="[img]../files/mes_images/".$t.".png[/img]";
$to=$_POST['to'];

$block=leo::mfa("select * from blok where (`by`='$usid' && `to`='$to') || (`by`='$to' && `to`='$usid')  ");
if(!$block){
$check=leo::mfa("select * from `mail` where (`by`='$usid' && `to`='$to') || (`by`='$to' && `to`='$usid') ");
if($check){
$cid=$check['cid'];
}else{
$scid=leo::mfa("select * from `mail` order by cid desc limit 1");
$cid=$scid?$scid['cid']+1:1;
}

$qu=leo::mq("insert into `mail` set `by`='$usid',`to`='$to',mesaj='$mes',vaxt='".time()."',oxu='yox',cid='$cid'");



}


}

}else{
header("location:../err?err=303");
}
?>
```

Comment: Check webserver and php logfiles

Comment: Well you wont get a 500 error from javascript. The issue will be in the PHP code that you are getting the javascript to run i.e. `ajax/sendPhoto.php` **So show us that as well**

Comment: What is in the preview tab of the ajax request? It could show the error if php errors are enabled.

Comment: Post full error message from firebug.

Comment: #1 edited.posted full error message

Comment: Please, **don't use an image** to show code. It's like photo retouching using notepad.

Comment: Not going to work from pictures of code. Paste the script as text

Comment: You need to look at the server logs to find out what the internal server error actually is.

Comment: @Quentin how can I find server logs?

Comment: Consult the manual for whatever HTTP server you are using?

Comment: The 500 error comes from the PHP part, not from the javascript. It's generated by the server the script crashes. Is it possible that your database functions `leo::mfa()` or `leo::mq()` throw exceptions (that are not catched in your code)? This would explain the error message.

Comment: @ul90 how can I catch exception in my class codes? leo::mq() is only mysql_query()

Comment: @FuadPashayev use `try { ... } catch($exception) {}` blocks to catch exceptions in your code. But if there is really an exception, you should find the root cause (maybe incorrect/no connection to the database, syntax error in your query strings etc.).

Comment: @ul90 but it sometimes works sometimes not works,what can it be?

Comment: @FuadPashayev by the way, i see this in your code: `$block=leo::mfa("select * from blok where (`by`='$usid' && `to`='$to') || (`by`='$to' && `to`='$usid')  ");` is the table name really `blok` or is this a typo and should be `block`?

Comment: @FuadPashayev if it sometimes works, try to catch the exceptions (if there are any) and write some debugging messages in the `catch()` block into an logfile (maybe using `error_log`) and try this way to find the error.

Comment: I'll use `catch()` but I don't have any information about `error_log` can you help me?

Comment: @FuadPashayev read the php documentations on http://php.net (for error_log: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php)